# Spacing issue with tocloft package when generating list of equations

Tags: spacing, lists, tocloft

I'm a LaTeX beginner so I apologize if this is a silly question, but I haven't been able to find a solution. I am writing a dissertation and would like to generate a list of equations, similar to a list of tables or figures. I took the solution presented by [gmedina here](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=428). It works great, so long as I have less than 10 equations per chapter. However, for equations of X.10 and above, there is a spacing issue as shown below. Is there a way to fix this? A similar question was asked a while ago but the suggestions provided didn't seem to work for me. ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96801/spacing-issue-when-using-tocloft-and-fontspec-together))

[image: Spacing problem for equations 1.10 and higher.]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}  

\begin{document}
\listofmyequations
\chapter{Chapter one}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\myequations{This is an equation.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome,, put `\renewcommand{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{3em}` after defining the list.

Comment: @Johannes_B Ups... beaten by a few seconds `:-)` Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @campa No, i already upvoted. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! And thank you for telling me exactly where to place the code, the solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a more automatic way, but the width of the label is controlled by the length `\cftXnumwidth`, where `X` stands for the counter you have defined with `\newlistof`. A possible solution is then to issue e.g.

```
\addtolength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{1em}
```